# Why do I get E2029 error when trying to implement a class helper for string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

We want to create a very convenient and stable conversion of data types, here string data type conversion using `class helper` feature in Delphi.

```
type
  TStringHelper = class helper for String
  public
    function AsBoolean: Boolean;
    ...
  end;

{ TStringHelper }

function TStringHelper.AsBoolean: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  try
    Result := StrToBool(Self);
  except
  end;
end;
```

When I try to compile the above code in Delphi XE2, I get:

> E2029 "declaration expected but string found"

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: You want a `record helper`.

Comment: also not working:   TStringhelp = record helper for String
  public
    function AsBoolean: Boolean;
  end;   :-(

Comment: We don't know what's *not working*. Be specific. As first I saw that you used `class helper` instead of `record helper`. Anyway, it hurts to see such exception swallowing. Let them raise, otherwise you may get invalid result when casting cannot be performed.

Comment: Error is E2029 "declaration expected but string found"

Comment: You can use `TryStrToBool` if you need to handle the exceptional case. However, the correct design here is to raise the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a `string` type you need to use a `record` helper rather than a `class` helper.

```
type
  TStringHelper = record helper for string
    ....  
  end;
```

Note that record helpers for fundamental data types (e.g. `Integer`, `double`, `string` etc.) were only introduced in XE3, so if you have an older version you are out of luck.