# use XE3 lang feature with XE 2 compiler

Tags: delphi

we recently wanted to use a Delphi language Feature ([string helper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847356/why-do-i-get-e2029-error-when-trying-to-implement-a-class-helper-for-string) under XE 2 which has been  avail. since Version XE 3.  In our project team we still use XE 2,  only 1 guy updated already to XE 8 for checking our conversions problems while switching to XE 8 in advance.  Due too poor dunit test coverage of our project, a few issues while porting the code to XE 8 and the useage of eg. RAVE Report we are still using X2.

Is there any solution to use one class and compile this unit with XE 8 and used the compiled dcu afterwards with XE 2.
Put the hole new lang Feature stuff into a DLL is a "working" but not desired solution, any other way ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any solution to use one class and compile this unit with XE8 and use the compiled .dcu afterwards with XE2.

No. The .dcu files are not compatible between different compiler versions.

Comment: Delphi 2006 and 2007 excluded :D